# Script (automatizar campos de um site)

Tags: node.js, script

Olá, me passaram uma tarefa que eu não sei como começar, automatizar uns campos de um determinado site, para não precisar ficar digitando eles todos os meses, foi me dado uma planilha com vários valores, e eu teria que salva-los linha por linha. Bem, eu estou perdida, ficaria grata se alguém pode-se me auxiliar. Fazer um script que automatize o preenchimento desses campos, já tentei usar o imacro, mas o pc de acesso fica em outro estado

Comment: Caroline, queremos certamente ajudar mas primeiro tens de nos dar um problema concreto para podermos ajudar. Só falar de um problema vagamente não nos possibilita ajudar... podes [edit] a pergunta e juntar mais detalhes?

Comment: Se entendi bem, a @Caroline precisa criar testes automatizados estilo Selenium WebDriver para que sejam executados de forma semelhante a um ambiente de integração contínua.

Comment: Olá, obrigada, já tentei o selenium nao sei como faço para mudar os valores de volta, não tem como fazer de outra forma?

Comment: Java e NodeJS na mesma pergunta?

Comment: Pablo desculpa, e que a linguagem está em java, mas me indicaram fazer um cURL pelo node.js, ai coloquei os dois sem querer.